# Apache RewriteRule for URLs with % codes

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect a url like:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/directory/p%3E%20%3Cp%3Efashion/tshirts
http://www.mywebsite.com/directory/p%3E%20somewhere/else
```

To

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/directory
```

However how do I tell my rewrites to look for % codes?

I have tried just whacking it in:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/p%3E%20%3Cp%3Efashion/tshirts http://www.mywebsite.com/directory [R,L,NE,NC]
```

Tried adding quotes around the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^"directory/p%3E%20%3Cp%3Efashion/tshirts" http://www.mywebsite.com/directory [R,L,NE,NC]
```

And tried putting the unencoded version to test:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/</p>%20<p>fashion/tshirts http://www.mywebsite.com/directory [R,L,NE,NC]
```

None of them redirect. I just receive a 404 as expected.

Any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^directory\/p\>\ \<p\>fashion\/tshirts http://www.mywebsite.com/directory [R,L,NC]`

Comment: We have a winner :) Make it answer and I'll accept it

Comment: As is illustrated by the above example, `RewriteRule` matches against the %-decoded URL, not the %-encoded URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to handle URLs like this.

**1. Match encoded URL** (as you've attempted):

```
RewriteRule ^directory/p>\s<p>fashion/tshirts /directory [R,L,NC]
```

Or with quotes:

```
RewriteRule "^directory/p> <p>fashion/tshirts" /directory [R,L,NC]
```

Only difference is that you should use `\s` or `" "` for matching a space.

**2. Match original URL using hex codes** (more generic solution):

```
RewriteRule ^directory/p\x3E\x20\x3Cp\x3Efashion/tshirts /dir [R,L,NC]
```

As you can see you need to use `\x3E` for matching `3E`.